# Prove derivative of $a^x$ with limit definition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

> Define $e(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+x/n \right)^{n}$
>
> Define $l(x)=e^{-1}(x)$ (since $e$ can be shown to be invertible)
>
> Define $A(a,x)=e(x\cdot l(a)),a>0$
>
> Prove that the following limit exists and find its value:
>
> $$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{A(a,x)-A(a,x_0)}{x-x_0},a>0$$

The issue that I have with this problem is that I need to be able to prove the limit WITHOUT yet having proved that $A(a,x)=a^x$ is true $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}\ge0$.  So I'm honestly not sure how to go about this from here.  Without being able to write it that way, how can I make any progress with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I would rewrite
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{A(a,x)-A(a,x_0)}{x-x_0}$$
as 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{e^{x\log a}-e^{x_0\log a}}{x-x_0} = e^{x_0\log a}\log a \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{h\log a}-1}{h\log a} = A(a,x_0)\log a.$$

Comment: That was really helpful; I didn't realize that second step right there.  Thank you very much.